# How to merge files from one branch's directory into another branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging, git-checkout

Simple example.  This is 'master':

```
root
    - index.html
    - readme.md
```

This is a branch called 'dev':

```
root
    src
        - index.jade
    dist
        - index.html
```

I'd like to take the index.html file (or all files, really) in the 'dist' folder of the 'dev' branch and replace or merge it with the one in the root directory of my master branch.  I've tried, from master:

```
git checkout dev dist/
```

But it produces this result:

```
root
    dist
        - index.html
    - index.html
```

Clearly not what I want.  Is git capable of doing what I want it to do or will I just have to whip up a script?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show the desired post-merge structure of the repository in the same way that you have shown the undesired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the `subtree` merge strategy, or the `subtree[=<path>]` option to the `recursive` merge strategy.

From the [`git-merge` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies), the description of the `subtree` strategy:

> **`subtree`**
>
> This is a modified recursive strategy. When merging trees A and B, if B corresponds to a subtree of A, B is first adjusted to match the tree structure of A, instead of reading the trees at the same level. This adjustment is also done to the common ancestor tree.

And the description of the `subtree[=<path>]` option to the `recursive` merge strategy:

> **`subtree[=<path>]`**
>
> This option is a more advanced form of *subtree* strategy, where the strategy makes a guess on how two trees must be shifted to match with each other when merging. Instead, the specified path is prefixed (or stripped from the beginning) to make the shape of two trees to match.

In your case, if `master` is the current branch the following command will merge the contents of the `dist/` directory from the `dev` branch into the root directory (you will have the opportunity to resolve conflicts should there be any):

```
git merge --no-ff -s recursive -X subtree=dist dev
```

If, instead, you wish to merge changes into the `dist/` directory, checkout the `dev` branch then run:

```
git merge --no-ff -s recursive -X subtree=dist master
```

The `subtree` strategy figures out how to "shift" the trees.  You can then checkout `master` and fast-forward to the new merge commit on the `dev` branch.

Comment: Tried out your command but I got the same result (the whole 'dist' directory is being added to the master branch instead of just it's content).

Comment: You merged `dev` into `master` right (`master` the first parent of the merge commit), not the other way around?  If so, is the repository published somewhere in order to see what's going on?

Comment: Yes, I ran the command from `master`.  Here's a test repo: https://github.com/eggbit/test

Comment: Ah right, that test repo is a fast-forward from `master` to `dev`; try it with `--no-ff` (updating answer now).

Comment: Thanks for the update.  The `--no-ff` flag did the trick and it's producing the right result now, thanks!  Running into a bit of a problem with updating, though.  So I run that merge command and it does what I want it to do, but if I then update `index.html` in `dev` and hop over to `master` and run the merge command again, I get the "already up to date" message.

Comment: Alright, I've figured it out.  The `subtree` switch for first merge needs to look like this: `subtree=dist origin/dev` while subsequent merges need to look like this: `subtree=dist dev`.  Not sure exactly why this is but it's working.

Comment: OK, glad you figured it out :)