# subtree merging master into branch: -s recursive -Xsubtree=?

Tags: git

In the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging), section "Subtree merging", it says:

> You can also do the opposite – make changes in the `rack` subdirectory of your master branch and then merge them into your `rack_branch` branch later to submit them to the maintainers or push them upstream.

That's exactly what I'd like to do. In the simple example it works (see also my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051686/git-merge-from-subtree-folder-in-master-to-branch-root)), so if I make changes in `rack` on `master` and commit them, I can do something like

```
git checkout rack_branch
git merge --squash -s recursive -Xsubtree master
```

and commit the to `rack_branch`. But in my project with a more complex directory structure, it doesn't work. Git doesn't figure out the right directory structure, and populates the branch `rack` (which is  a subdirectory) with the entire structure of the superfolder.

The answer, in my humble newbee opinion, is to use `-Xsubtree=PATH`, because then (as it says in the git-merge doc):

> ...Instead, the specified path is prefixed (or stripped from the beginning) to make the shape of two trees to match.

But how do you specify the correct path in this specific example? It's on level up the directory tree i.e.

```
git merge --squash -s recursive -Xsubtree=.. master
```

That doesn't work. I should add that `-Xsubtree=rack` (or the equivalent for my project) doesn't work either (i.e. neither the "strip" nor "prepend" strategy works. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I just stumbled across [this blog post](https://blog.plenz.com/2011-02/criss-cross-subtree-merges.html), and adding the `--no-ff` option seems to work. Maybe someone can explain why this is necessary? Should this be necessary? Thanks in advance.

EDIT2: Do I understand correctly that the `--no-ff` option appends *all* the commits from the master branch, even those which have nothing to do with that subdirectory? That wouldn't be good. Is there a workaround?

EDIT3: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686681/how-to-merge-files-from-one-branchs-directory-into-another-branch). I realized now that had read that post hours ago, but didn't pick up on the `--no-ff` flag. If this problem is so common, then the `--no-ff` flag should IMHO be the default behaviour of `-s recursive -Xsubtree=PATH`, particularly if a PATH is explicitly provided.